# Работа с HashSet в Java

Tags: java

Является ли это Best Practice, можно вообще так писать, а именно скажем если элемент уже в коллекции существует выбрасывать исключение с сообщением.

```
static private Set<A> a = new HashSet<>();   
public A save(A object) {
    if (!a.contains(object)) {
        a.add(object);
        return object;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This object exists in the system already!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Если это удовлетворяет бизнес-логике, и метод не находится под высокой нагрузкой, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: Писать можно, но не думаю что это Best Practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коллекция `HashSet` [построена на базе `HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java). В обоих случаях, для метода `contains()` и `add()` выполняется итерация по элементам коллекции. Для `HashSet` / `HashMap`, в общем случае, это быстрые операции, которые выполняются за `O(1)`, т.е. за константное время. [Статья в тему](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/simple-big-o-notation-post.html).

Тем не менее, лишнего обхода коллекции можно избежать, исключив метод `contains()` поскольку метод [add(E)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) и так проверяет наличие элемента и возвращает boolean:

```
if ( !a.add(object) ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
}
return object;
```

Также, я бы подумал нужно ли вообще возвращать что-то из метода. Из приведенного кода не видно смысла возвращать ссылку на объект, которая передана методу как аргумент. Если элемент не добавится, кидается `RuntimeException`, этого достаточно.

В целом, обычный код, без явного code smell. По одному методу не всегда можно судить об эффективности алгоритма. Если вам в этом месте нужен экспепшн - кидайте эксепшн. Это определяется только логикой вашего приложения.

---

Comment: это ответ не совсем на тот вопрос, что был у ТС как мне кажется.

Comment: возврат аргумента - это мелкое удобство, можно писать `save( otherObject.getSomeA() ).someAMethod().anotherMethod()`. Экономия точек с запятой :) Но в вопросе очень не хватает примера использования.